# mantain items values when postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

I have the following script, that allows me to take the hour difference between two `<input type="text">` and set the result into another input box.

```
function restarHoras1() {
        inicio = document.getElementById("Start1").value;
        fin = document.getElementById("End1").value;
        inicioMinutos = parseInt(inicio.substr(3, 2));
        inicioHoras = parseInt(inicio.substr(0, 2));
        finMinutos = parseInt(fin.substr(3, 2));
        finHoras = parseInt(fin.substr(0, 2));
        transcurridoMinutos = finMinutos - inicioMinutos;
        transcurridoHoras = finHoras - inicioHoras;

        if (transcurridoMinutos < 0) {
            transcurridoHoras--;
            transcurridoMinutos = 60 + transcurridoMinutos;
        }
        if (transcurridoMinutos < 10) {
            transcurridoMinutos = "0" + transcurridoMinutos;
        }
        if (transcurridoHoras < 0) {
            transcurridoHoras = 24 + transcurridoHoras;
        }
        horas = transcurridoHoras.toString();
        minutos = transcurridoMinutos.toString();
        if (horas.length < 2) {
            horas = "0" + horas;
        }
        if (minutos.length < 2) {
            minutos = minutos + "0";
        }
        document.getElementById("Duration1").value = horas + ":" + minutos;
        if (fin.length != 5) {
            document.getElementById("End1").style.backgroundColor = 'orangered';
            return;
        }
        if (fin.length = 5) {
            document.getElementById("End1").style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
            return;
        }
    }
```

It's working all right, except that the values gets deleted when postback. It should mantain the values into the `<input>`. How can I do this?

Comment: You can use asp.net textbox control instead of html textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `asp:TextBox` instead of a traditional html input. Thus:

```
  inicio = document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").value;
  fin = document.getElementById("<%= TextBox2.ClientID %>").value;
```